# i use jQuery .attr in console google : "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to recover the data of the first mail from [here](https://maildrop.cc/inbox/test).
I am using `$('#inboxtbl tbody tr').attr('data-id')`
in the Google Chrome console and I get below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function at <anonymous>:1:25
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: have you included jquery cdn??

Comment: This would mean that the selector ```#inboxtbl tbody tr``` yielded no results. Are you sure it is correct? And does ```$``` exist?

Comment: @TimVN that has nothing to do with it

Comment: @TimVN — No. jQuery will no elements in the array would just have `attr` return a useless value. It wouldn't error.

Comment: ^^ specifically, it returns `undefined`. It's the **only** time it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Deepak Hmm, haven't used jQuery in a long time. Thought that's what happens, my bad.

Comment: I am assuming that jQuery is included. If you want to read data attribute, simply do this `$('#inboxtbl tbody tr').data('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've loaded jQuery on the page you're debugging, `$` in the Chrome devtools console isn't jQuery, it's effectively a shortcut for [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) if you provide a second argument). So you'd use `getAttribute`, not `attr`:

```
$('#inboxtbl tbody tr').getAttribute('data-id')
```

(`$$` is effectively a shortcut for [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), too [or [`Element#querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) if you provide a second argument]. The full list is [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities).)